# How to exclude data in the where condition while conflicts with another condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'd like to retrieve the bill when 
`charge1 + charge2 is not equal to the BillAmount`, but in the meantime, exclude when `charge1 + charge2 + 0.01 = BillAmount` or when `charge1 + charge2 - 0.01 = BillAmount`.  How do I achieve this in sql?  The way I did does not work correctly.

```
SELECT BIllAmount, Charge1, Charge2 
FROM Table
WHERE BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2
OR (BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 + 0.01 
     OR BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 - 0.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of those conditions will be true, because something is not going to be equal.

I think the logic you want is:

```
WHERE NOT (BillAmount = Charge1 + Charge2 OR
           BillAmount = Charge1 + Charge2 + 0.01 OR
           BillAmount = Charge1 + Charge2 - 0.01
          )
```

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 AND
      BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 + 0.01 AND
      BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 - 0.01
```

Note: I hope your values are *not* floating point/double data types.  Comparing for equality can produce unexpected results.  This is not a problem with `decimal`/`numeric`/`money` data types.

Comment: The data type is money so it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

First you filtered out the row where `billamount <> charge1 + charge2`..Then from that you can apply your next `<>` condition
   Try below code

```
Select BillAmount, Charge1, Charge2
from
(
SELECT BillAmount, Charge1, Charge2 
FROM Table
WHERE BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2
) as t
Where BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 + 0.01 
     OR BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2 - 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this :

```
SELECT BillAmount, Charge1, Charge2 
FROM Table
WHERE BillAmount <> Charge1 + Charge2
AND Charge1 + Charge2 + 0.01 <> BillAmount
AND Charge1 + Charge2 - 0.01 <> BillAmount
```

That way, you will select every occurence where your BillAmount is not equal to the sum of the two charges and not equal to the sum of the two charges with a difference of 0.01.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common thing to do when working with billing, avoid the penny difference.  Nothing fancy is needed.

```
SELECT BillAmount, Charge1, Charge2 
FROM Table
WHERE BillAmount - (Charge1 + Charge2) not between -0.01 and 0.01
```